# how to use the Addition function in xpath

Tags: xpath

I have a xml file

```
<productID>2893</productID>
<quantity>13</quantity>
<price>10</price>
```

via php script

```
$one=array(
    array_shift($prod->xpath('productID')),
    array_shift($prod->xpath('quantity')),
    array_shift($prod->xpath('price'))
```

I need to multiply by 3 the value of the node price,to write it in csv

```
productID|quantity|price
2893|13|30
```

I have already made ​​the script, but I can not perform the multiplication before writing the value in csv file.

File XML

```
<data>
<result>
    <product>
    <productID> 2893 </productID>
    <quantity> 13 </quantity>
    <price> 10 </price>
    </product>
</result></data>
```

---

PHP Script

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file('file.xml');
$csv=fopen('file.csv','w');
foreach ($xml->xpath('/data/result/product') as $prod) {
  $one=array(
    array_shift($prod->xpath('productID')),
    array_shift($prod->xpath('quantity')),
    array_shift($prod->xpath('price'))
  );
  fputcsv($csv,$one,'|');
}


fclose($csv);
```

Comment: You should add the part of your script doing the output to your question.

Comment: in the csv file ,I have to get the result "price * 3 = 30"

Comment: Wouldn't `$one=array(array_shift($prod->xpath('productID')), array_shift($prod->xpath('quantity')), 3*array_shift($prod->xpath('price')));` work?

Comment: Just curious: what has this to do with addition or XPath, a per the subject and tag?